# why is my function "handleexpression" not working as expected ? (Calculator app)

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, calculator

when I press the clear button , I am left with the first digit/operator the typed in .

like the very first screen:

[first screen of the calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j89nT.jpg)

(Also I don't understand why it is giving a warning that every child should have unique key though I have done so)

second screen :
[entered the expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry6pi.jpg)

third screen :
[after pressing the clear button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u08dS.jpg)

Project code :

**calculator.js**

```
export const initialState = {
  expression: "",
  currentValue: "0",
  operator: null,
  previousValue: null
};

export const handleNumber = (value, state) => {

  if (state.currentValue === "0") {
    return { currentValue: `${value}` };
  }

  return {
    currentValue: `${state.currentValue}${value}`
  };
};

const handleexpression = (value, state) => {
  if (!value) {
    state.expression = "";
    return;
  }
  state.expression += value
}

const calculator = (type, value, state) => {
  switch (type) {

    case "number":
      handleexpression(value, state);
      return handleNumber(value, state);

    case "operator":
      handleexpression(value, state);
      return {
        ...state,
        operator: value,
        previousValue: state.currentValue,
      };

    case "equal":

      return handleEqual(state);

    case "clear":
      handleexpression("", state);
      return initialState;

};

export default calculator;
```

**index.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = initialState;

  handleTap = (type, value) => {
    this.setState(state => calculator(type, value, state));
  };


  btnslist = [[7, 8, 9, "*"],
  [4, 5, 6, "-"],
  [1, 2, 3, "+"]];


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Text style={styles.value}>
            {this.state.expression}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.value}>
            {parseFloat(this.state.currentValue).toLocaleString()}
          </Text>
          <Row>
            <Button
              key="C"
              text="C"
              theme="secondary"
              onPress={() => this.handleTap("clear")}
            />
          </Row>

          {/* mapping out all numbers */}
          {
            this.btnslist.map((btns) => (
              <Row>
                {btns.map((btn) => (

                  Number.isInteger(btn) || btn == '.' ?

                    <Button key={`${btn}`} text={`${btn}`} onPress={() => this.handleTap("number", btn)} />

                    :

                    <Button key={`${btn}`} text={`${btn}`} theme="accent" onPress={() => this.handleTap("operator", `${btn}`)} />
                ))}
              </Row>
            ))
          }

        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When `btn` is a number or ".", this might lead to duplicate keys, especially if you have repeating numbers or operators. You have to make sure keys are unique to avoid having all those warnings

Comment: @ChrisG all calculators are different , I can't find any way of duplication of keys , though it will be really helpful if u can explain briefly..

Comment: you are using the values of the buttons directly as a key

Comment: @LuciferStix you have no key on the outer Row that's being mapped from btnslist, add one there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.